# Version Control System for Dynamics CRM 2011/2013

Tags: version-control, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have started using Git for my other development projects (PHP, HTML, JavaScript, etc.) and can now see how beneficial it is, however I've been unable to find anything similar for Dynamics CRM 2011/2013 as a lot of the solution development is done within the web interface.

I'm guessing this is not possible, but could someone with more experience than me please confirm this or let me know which tools I should be looking into?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Visual Studio Developer Toolkit available in the SDK to version control your plugins and web resources initially.  I'd recommend this as your first step.

If you choose to take it further you can also look at using the [SolutionPackager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602997.aspx) tool to version control your solutions.  This will split out your solution zip file into separate version controllable files for each component.  It works best when you follow the developer workflow outlined in the linked MSDN article